# Where do the circles x^2+y^2=1 and (x - 6/5)^2+(y-1/2)^2=2 intersect?

Tags: plotting

I need to plot these two equations but I can't figure what commands to use.

Comment: `Solve[x^2 + y^2 == 1 && (x - 6/5)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 == 2 , {x, y}]`

Comment: I have figured that out but i can't figure out how to plot it on the same graph as two circles to show the intersection. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way I found to show both circles and their intersections:

```
circle1 = x^2 + y^2 == 1;
circle2 = (x - 6/5)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 == 2;
Show[
 Region[ImplicitRegion[circle1, {x, y}]],
 Region[ImplicitRegion[circle2, {x, y}]],
 Region[ImplicitRegion[circle1 && circle2, {x, y}]]
]
```

I was hoping that `RegionPlot` would help here, but it seems to struggle with the intersection points (edit: the documentation mentions that `RegionPlot` only deals with 2D regions):

```
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[circle1, {x, y}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[circle2, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[{reg1, reg2, RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Anyway, I hope this is enough to get you going.

Comment: f you specify AspectRatio->Automatic it even looks like circles

Comment: @DanielHuber Wait, what? I tried to get the aspect ratio right by using `AspectRatio -> 1` but it wasn't working. So that's what I needed to do...

Comment: `AspectRatio` was invented to confuse us.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of MMA there used to be the function: ImplicitPlot. But, this functionality is now incorporated into CountourPlot. With this function your example looks like:

```
ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, (x - 6/5)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 == 2}, {x, -1, 
  3}, {y, -1, 2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]